# Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below code which for instance work as excepted but won't work in the Future :

```
    total.name = 'New_Row'
    total_df = total.to_frame().T
    total_df.at['New_Row', 'CURRENCY'] = ''
    total_df.at['New_Row', 'MANDATE'] = Portfolio
    total_df.at['New_Row', 'COMPOSITE'] = 'GRAND TOTAL'
    total_df.set_index('COMPOSITE',inplace=True)
```

since an error is thrown in

```
FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and 
will raise in a future error of pandas. Value 'GRAND TOTAL' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
  total_df.at['New_Row', 'COMPOSITE'] = 'GRAND TOTAL'
```

How to fix this ?

variable total is :

```
CURRENCY
MANDATE             Mandate_Test
USD AMOUNT          123
LOCAL AMOUNT        12
Beg. Mkt            123
End. Mkt            456
Name: New_Row, dtype: object
```

Comment: So make sure the entry for `['New_Row', 'COMPOSITE']` is a float64. `'GRAND TOTAL'` is a string, so that won't work.

Comment: what makes you say the second answer is AI-generated?

Comment: @OCa because before going on SO i asked chat gpt to see if it can help. And it gave me the same wrong answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is bug -  [BUG: incompatible dtype when creating string column with loc #55025](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55025) . In next version of pandas should be solved.

Comment: I think you are right, but I will accept when I will be sure in case someone got an other explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the whole column to None and then making it string type. This should probably also work with rows (as in your case) or cells etc.

df['CURRENCY'] = None

df['CURRENCY'] = df['CURRENCY'].astype(str)

Answer (score 0):

Convert when open, for ex:
df_new = pd.read_excel(df_new, converters={'Title': str, 'Description': str})