# Pandas: How to avoid FutureWarning when setting bool value to NaN (missing)?

Tags: pandas, boolean, future-warning

I want to apply comparison operator to Pandas DataFrame. In case the source data value is missing then my result bool table should contain missing values as well. My code:

```
>>> pd.__version__
'2.1.1'
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1.2, 2.2, np.nan], [1.1, np.nan, 3.3]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
>>> res = df.gt(1.0)
>>> res
res
    A      B      C
0  True   True  False
1  True  False   True
```

Attempt to assign NaN value to original missing positions yields FutureWarning

```
>>> res[df.isna()]=pd.NA
FutureWarning: Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value 'nan' has dtype incompatible with bool, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
```

**How to get the results correctly without warning?**

*Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185621/setting-an-item-of-incompatible-dtype-is-deprecated-and-will-raise-in-a-future-e) is unrelated as it does not solve entering of missing values.*

Comment: IIUC, use `res = df.gt(1.0).where(df.notna(), pd.NA)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is combinations `boolean` with missing values, so convert mask to [Nullable Boolean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/boolean.html):

```
res = df.gt(1.0).astype('boolean')

res[df.isna()]=pd.NA
print (res)
      A     B     C
0  True  True  <NA>
1  True  <NA>  True

res = df.gt(1.0).astype('boolean').mask(df.isna())
print (res)
      A     B     C
0  True  True  <NA>
1  True  <NA>  True
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution avoids warning message and returns DataFrame with bool dtype.