# Incompatible Dtype Is Deprecated

Tags: python, pandas, casting, plotly-dash, deprecated

My script (Dash-Plotly server), I have started to get an error

> FutureWarning:
>
> Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in
> a future error of pandas. Value '999999999' has dtype incompatible
> with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.

This was not coming before but I did had updated packages like Pandas and others.

It is easy to know which line has error as I have only two places with '999999999'.

In my code, I have a need to fill NaN with a really high Number so I chose '999999999' and fill df with it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'subject': ['site0.microsoft.com', 'site1.microsoft.com', 'site2.microsoft.com', 'site3.microsoft.com', 'site4.microsoft.com', 'site5.microsoft.com'],
'issuer': ["Let's Encrypt", "Let's Encrypt", np.nan, "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", np.nan],
'expiry': ['2023-10-02 19:24:31', '2023-09-12 12:03:23', '2023-08-03 00:00:00', '2022-09-15 07:04:04', np.nan, '2023-07-28 19:29:16'], 
'owner': [ 'Kubernetes Support L1', 'Kubernetes Support L2', 'john.doe@microsoft.com', 'IT-Applications Support L1', 'IT-Applications Support L2', 'Wildcard - Network']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.fillna('999999999', inplace=True)
```

This fillna like is causing this warning message.
The Server runs fine, it just this warning error it spits out. Trying to get help how do I get rid of this error.

This above code is pretty similar to what I have in Production Server but when you run in Python Interpreter, this won't generate the error. The error is when you start Server.

I've read majority articles/asks in SO but did not understood any reasoning. e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284697/erro-futurewarning-dtype-incompatible-with-float64-please-explicitly-cast) and this one [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77185621/setting-an-item-of-incompatible-dtype-is-deprecated-and-will-raise-in-a-future-e)

Is there a one-liner you can think of?
thank you very much.

Comment: With quotes it is a string, not a number.

Comment: That exact code fails? Those columns all are dtype `object` and should not generate that problem. Can you print `df.dtypes` before the fillna to see what the column dtypes are? I'd expect a float64 to get that error.

Comment: And can you include `pd.__version__` for the fail?

Comment: It seems like expiry is actually a float and you'd want to fill issuer and expiry differently. issuer '999999999' is odd. Perhaps `df.issuer.fillna("<unknown>", inplace=True)` and `df.expiry,fillna(999999999.0, inplace=True)`.

Comment: In fact, I think this answers it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284697/erro-futurewarning-dtype-incompatible-with-float64-please-explicitly-cast

Comment: """subject      object
issuer       object
expiry       object
expiry2      object
REM           int64
owner        object
dtype: object
2.1.1
C:\...\...\app.py:577: FutureWarning:

Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '999999999' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
"""

Hi @tdelaney added df.dtypes and pd.version before fillna.

Comment: `subject      object
issuer       object
expiry       object
expiry2      object
REM           int64
owner        object
dtype: object
2.1.1
C:\...\...\app.py:577: FutureWarning:

Setting an item of incompatible dtype is deprecated and will raise in a future error of pandas. Value '999999999' has dtype incompatible with float64, please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.
`